# java.lang.IllegalStateException when launching the Alert Dialog second time

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-alertdialog

[image]
        I have created the Alert Dialog(with checkbox at the bottom), and launching it on the click of Preference. First time alert dialog launched successfully but second time following exception came :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

MainActivity.java

```
final View checkBoxView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.checkbox, null);   /*to inflate dialog with checkbox */
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        System.out.println("******** CheckBox Clicked *********");
        /* Save to shared preferences */
    }
});
checkBox.setText("Use by default for this action");

Preference pref = (Preference) findPreference("preference");
        pref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
                final CharSequence[] items = {"BT Smart Settings by ABC",
                        "BT Smart Settings by XYZ",
                        "BT Smart Settings by DEFAULT"};

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Complete action using");
                builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        System.out.println("************* clicked-item :"+item);

                    }
                });
                builder.setView(checkBoxView);
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Any help in this regard will be well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `alert.dismiss()` on your `AlertDialog` once you are done with it.

Comment: Hi Kazekage Gaara, thanks for the reply but still no luck, same exception is coming

Comment: You will need to dismiss the AlertDialog. The Exception clearly says this : the child already has a parent.

Answer (score 0):

this will help you -:

```
if(checkBoxView.getParent() == null) {
 builder.setView(checkBoxView);
} else {
 checkBoxView = null; //set your view to null then set the required values again
final View checkBoxView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.checkbox, null);   /*to inflate dialog with checkbox */
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        System.out.println("******** CheckBox Clicked *********");
        /* Save to shared preferences */
    }
});
checkBox.setText("Use by default for this action");
builder.setView(checkBoxView);

}
```